# Validating my application using VALIDATE in xcode - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, validation, app-store-connect

I need to use the validate functionality in xcode. I need to check if i have not done anything illegal while programming.

I know that i have to login to my iTunes connect account and add a new app. (I did this step)
Next i have to fill in the Language preferred, App name, SKU number and bundle ID

1.) what should i enter for SKU number ?

2.) I only want to submit the app for validation (and not submit the app to appstore). So what is the process i should follow after entering the above details (note:I only need to validate and not submit)

3.) What should i select in Bundle ID dropdown. is it the `appname -*` or the `appname - com.me.app` ?

if i select `appname - *` it will prompt the `Bundle ID Suffix` what should i add there /

4.) I have given a false application name to its App Name column (since i am not going to submit this to app store), So will i be able to add an App again giving the same Bundle Id and SKU number ?

Comment: Hi shajem, did you try any of my suggestions yet? Would like to know how you are getting on :)

Comment: @Luke Thank you for your reply. It sure did help. BTW, do you know any automated process where i could check if my app will get rejected from apple's review process? (I am using xcode 4.3.1)

Comment: I am not aware of anything that can do this I'm afraid - but if you are the team leader or a developer/admin user within iTunes Connect, you should receive automatic emails from Apple, when your app's status has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The SKU is a unique number that you come up with that will help you to identify the app. It can be anything that you desire, for example `001` or `0001`.

2) Follow the remaining steps in iTunes Connect, until you get to "Ready to upload binary". (and then hit that button) Feel free to use placeholder (ie, temporary) screenshots and files for the app icon. Just ensure they're of the correct resolution to keep Apple happy for now.

Once the app has changed to the "waiting for upload" state, then when you build an archive of the app in Xcode and then go to validate, then login with your info, and it will validate your app binary file.

3) You need to pick the `appname - com.me.app` option.

4) You can add more apps again, but the app name, SKU and bundle ID will be different if it is a different app. If you want to reuse the app name that you've made, purely to test the validation of the app, then be sure to setup your app in Xcode using the same provisioning profiles, bundle ID and app name again.

Hope this helps!